# Issue with Pop up in Folium TimestampedGeoJson map

Tags: python, popup, geojson, folium

I am trying to visualize data from my pandas dataframe onto a map using Folium TimestampedGeoJson. My data frame contains Lats, Long, datetime and some other information.I am able to get the map working and visualize the lats, long along with color coding(based on a categorical variable) and radius of the circle (based on numerical variable) over the time period. However I am not able to get the pop ups.

My code for converting pandas dataframe to Geojson is :

```
def create_geojson_features(df):
    print('> Creating GeoJSON features...')
    features = []
    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        feature = {
            'type': 'Feature',
            'geometry': {
                'type':'Point', 
                'coordinates':[row['long'],row['lats']]

            },
            'properties': {
                'time': row['Instruction Date Time'].date().__str__(),
                'popup':row['pop_up_info'],
                'style': {'color' : row['color']},
                'icon': 'circle',
                'iconstyle':{
                    #'Color': row['color'],
                    'fillOpacity': 0.2,
                    'fillcolor':'crimson',
                    'stroke': 'true',
                    'weight':4,
                    'radius': row['Numerical_data']*40
                }
            }
        }
        features.append(feature)

    return features
```

And my code for plotting the Geojson data using Folium TimestampedGeojson is :

```
m_events = folium.Map(
    location=[52.45,-1.90],control_scale=True,
    zoom_start=7,
)

plugins.TimestampedGeoJson(
    {
        'type': 'FeatureCollection',
        'features': features
    },
    period='P1M',
    add_last_point=False,
    auto_play=False,
    loop=False,
    max_speed=1,
    loop_button=True,
    date_options='YYYY/MM/DD',
    time_slider_drag_update=True,
    duration='P2M'
).add_to(m_events)


m_events.save('m_events.html')
m_events
```

Everything works fine including the time slider. The only issue is the pop up not working.

Comment: Were you able to display the popups?

Answer (score 0):

try to use this in Geojson format : 'popup': str(row['pop_up_info'])
After this it should works fine